# What is $\Bbb E$? Is is $\Bbb R$ with the standard Euclidean topology?

Tags: general-topology, notation, terminology

What is $\Bbb E$?

I believe this is just alternative notation for $\Bbb R$ where $\Bbb R$ is assumed to have the standard Euclidean topology. Is this correct?

Is seems to be used in this way in Armstrong's Basic topology

Comment: I've seen $\mathbb{E}$ used to denote $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $n$ is left unspecified. However, I'm not sure how Armstrong is using it.

Comment: @Kevin He is making mention ot $\Bbb E^3$ for example and treating it like $\Bbb R^3$, but I am not certain that there are no differences. But I think you may be right, $\Bbb E$ may be a general way of referring to any number of dimensions on $\Bbb R^n$

Comment: I thought it was used so that there was no ambiguity in which metric you are using. So $E$ would denote the standard euclidean metric.

Comment: @Mr.Fry That was what I thought, thanks.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about the usage in Armstrong's book?. Or somewhere else (like your lecture notes or test from past exams)?

Comment: @MartinSleziak Generally terminology I suppose. But the question came from reading Armstrong, which just starts talking about $\Bbb E$ I believe on page 12 with "Let $f$ be a function between two euclidean space, say $f: \Bbb E^m \to \Bbb E^n$

Comment: Here is a related question: [What differences are between $\mathbb{E}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34172/what-differences-are-between-mathbben-and-mathbbrn)